# Swing form clears but data is still retained

Tags: java, swing

I have a swing form that I enter 4 values into and then a test file is generated based on 1 of the 4 available buttons being clicked.

The problem I am running into though is if I don't exit out after each use if I click a button twice the previous click's data is used to generate the 2nd file.

I thought clearing everything might fix it, and that made it so I could click 2 separate buttons and not have the 1st run's data in the 2nd's, but I'm not sure how to fix clicking the same button twice.

```
package GUI;
import Generators.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test_File_Generator implements  ActionListener {
JLabel intro;
JButton standard;
JButton ts;
JButton fa;
JButton fd;

JLabel name;
JButton testcaseFile;
JButton fullFile;

JLabel prefix;
JLabel sponsor;
JLabel email;
JLabel numRec;

JFrame frame;

public static JTextField prefixText;
public static JTextField sponsorText;
public static JTextField emailText;
public static JTextField numRecText;


JButton generate;
JButton clear;

Test_File_Generator() {
    JFrame jpn = new JFrame("Test File Generator");
    jpn.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jpn.setSize(400, 400);
    jpn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    intro = new JLabel("               Select a PCI Data Feed Type               ");
    standard = new JButton("Standard");
    tsys = new JButton("TS");
    faps = new JButton("FA");
    fdc = new JButton("FD");

    name = new JLabel("          Select the type of Standard File to generate         ");
    testcaseFile = new JButton("TC File");
    fullFile = new JButton("Full File");

    //Create text fields and labels
    prefix = new JLabel("Enter a Prefix: ");
    prefixText = new JTextField(30);
    sponsor = new JLabel("Enter a Sponsor: ");
    sponsorText = new JTextField(30);
    email = new JLabel("Enter a Email: ");
    emailText = new JTextField(30);
    numRec = new JLabel("Enter the number of records needed: ");
    numRecText = new JTextField(30);
    generate = new JButton("Generate");
    clear = new JButton("Clear");






    //jpn.add(new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT));

    jpn.add(prefix);
    jpn.add(prefixText);
    jpn.add(sponsor);
    jpn.add(sponsorText);
    jpn.add(email);
    jpn.add(emailText);
    jpn.add(numRec);
    jpn.add(numRecText);
    //jpn.add(name);

   // jpn.add(testcaseFile);
    //jpn.add(fullFile);

    jpn.add(intro);
    jpn.add(standard);
    jpn.add(ts);
    jpn.add(fa);
    jpn.add(fd);

    standard.addActionListener(this);
    ts.addActionListener(this);
    fa.addActionListener(this);
    fd.addActionListener(this);

    jpn.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create the frame on the event dispatching thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Test_File_Generator();
        }
    });
}

public void clearText(){
    prefixText.setText("");
    sponsorText.setText("");
    emailText.setText("");
    numRecText.setText("");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(standard)) SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (prefixText.getText().equals("") || sponsorText.getText().equals("") || emailText.getText().equals("") || numRecText.getText().equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All Fields Must Be Filled!");
            } else {
                new WFfgenerator().main();
                clearText();

            }
    }
    });

    else if(e.getSource().equals(ts)) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (prefixText.getText().equals("") || sponsorText.getText().equals("") || emailText.getText().equals("") || numRecText.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All Fields Must Be Filled!");
                } else {
                    try {
                        new TS_RecordCreator().main();
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    } else if(e.getSource().equals(fa)) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (prefixText.getText().equals("") || sponsorText.getText().equals("") || emailText.getText().equals("") || numRecText.getText().equals("")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All Fields Must Be Filled!");
                    } else {
                        try {
                            new FA_generator().main();
                        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
} else {
        if(e.getSource().equals(fd)) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (prefixText.getText().equals("") || sponsorText.getText().equals("") || emailText.getText().equals("") || numRecText.getText().equals("")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All Fields Must Be Filled!");
                    } else {
                        new FDmerchant_generator().main();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) ..

Comment: .. for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: You're posting a lot of code in your question, most of it completely unrelated to your problem at hand. Please do yourself and us a favor by trying to first isolate the problem. Create a new *small* program, ***very*** small, one that has enough code to compile and run for us, and all it does is reproduces the problem for us, and nothing more, a [mcve]. Your going through this process often allows you to better understand your own code and your problem leading to your being able to solve it yourself. Or if you can't we have a much better chance of being able to help. Good luck.

Comment: Just a guess but the use of SwingUtilities.invokeLater might mean that the ClearText call from the first click is happening after the second button click is processed.  Unless the routines take a long time, I'd remove the invoke threads and just run it all in the gui thread so one button click is fully processed before the next.  Also, you only call the clearText() method when you click the standard button.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay: yes, his use of SwingUtilities is not correct at all. He's queuing code onto the Swing event thread which is **already** on the event thread, which makes me think that he's very confused as to how Swing threading works. Also, his use of static fields is incorrect and gives a code smell to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this issue wrong, but was able to solve it.  I was trying to have the text cleared at the base form level.  Where it needed to be cleared was when it called the method.

I fixed this by going into each method that was called by a button push, and at the end of it, putting in variables to clear out the values.

I also added that same code to be executed after each button push so that I start with a blank form each time.

I also looked through everyone's comments and got rid of the swingUtility Invoke later calls.